# I cant properly shape a 2d array for a classifier

Tags: python, arrays, list, scikit-learn

I have an issue with the numpy.array method. I'm trying to set up an array of dimensions (73, 125) with my data, but when applying the .array method I get something like this

```
set arousal (73,) [list([3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]) # etc...
```

While instead I was expecting something like set arousal (73, 125).

This is my code

```
# Before this I imported the packages, the relevant datasets and did some preprocessing to drop "bad" data

info_en = info_clean[info_clean['QESTN_LANGUAGE'] == 'ENG']

rating_en = rating_clean[rating_clean['LANGUAGE'] == 'ENG']

info_en_set = info_en.copy()
ratings_set = rating_en.copy()

lArousal = []
lValence = []

for case in case_list:
    set = ratings_set[ratings_set['CASE'] == case]
    lArousal.append(list(set.loc[:,['AROUSAL_RATING']]['AROUSAL_RATING']))
    lValence.append(list(set.loc[:,['VALENCE_RATING_RECODED']]['VALENCE_RATING_RECODED']))
    
arrArousal = np.asarray(lArousal)
arrValence = np.asarray(lValence)
print('set arousal',arrArousal.shape,arrArousal)
print('set valence',arrValence.shape,arrValence)
```

When I try to train my sklearn classifier I get the error message "setting an array element with a sequence." that I can understand but I can't solve the list issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the for loop works for one dataset that I am testing but not for the other. In one case I correctly get the 2d array, in the other, I am stuck with this array of lists.